# Does the Russian 300mm "guided" rocket 9M949 use gyroscopes made in the USA?

Tags: united-states, military, russia, trade

One Ukrainian website seem to claim [that](https://defence-ua.com/weapon_and_tech/u_iskanderi_kalibri_ta_u_bilshosti_ozbrojennja_rf_znajdeni_komponeti_virobnitstva_krajin_nato-7434.html):

> Керована 300-мм ракета 9М949 ракетного комплексу "Торнадо-С": оптоволоконний гіроскоп для інерційної навігації. Виробництво - США.

in google translation:

> Guided 300-mm missile 9M949 missile system "Tornado-C": fiber-optic gyroscope for inertial navigation. Production - USA.

They also claim some smaller components on other systems like oscillators etc., which I find more plausible given similar analyses -- see annex in a RUSI report [here](https://static.rusi.org/special-report-202204-operation-z-web.pdf). But, IIRC gyroscopes are considered more militarily sensitive and aren't that easily exported. (Although Russia might not get them directly from the USA.)

Eh, I see the ultimate source of that claim is actually the same RUSI report, albeit no pictures on that:

> The 9M949 guided 300-mm
> rocket that forms the backbone of Russian precision artillery as a munition for the Tornado-S
> multiple launch rocket system uses a US-made fibre-optic gyroscope for its inertial navigation. [cited to:] Inspection of a recovered 9M949 gyroscope by the authors during fieldwork in April 2022.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [FOGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre-optic_gyroscope) says it's also used in other military systems, including artillery pieces etc.

Comment: From [an article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631070514001443) on such devices some "typical" suppliers listed are Northrop Grumman and Honeywell, so that kinda reinforces my feeling this is not the same as buying memory chips.

Comment: And some designs were [definitely](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5037205) patented by the aforementioned companies, which I'm guessing would have limited availability.

Comment: And yeah, some gyros [are](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/documents/regulations-docs/2339-category-7-navigation-and-avionics-2/file) definitely export-controlled by the USA, with somewhat complicated limits placed on accuracy etc. I'm less sure if Russia was (before 2022) in the list of countries that those restrictions applied to. (The list of countries is in a separate document that I can't find right now.)

Comment: However, China, Russia and (ahem) Venezuela are listed in that doc as being (broadly) prohibited from acquiring [even] software that can be used in missiles, so I'd venture a guess that the gyro prohibitions applied to Russia.

Comment: OTHO, outside that claim, I'm having trouble even determining if 9M949 even exist as such. The bunch of Wikipedia pages (incl. those in Russian) about 300mm Russian rocket systems don't seem to mention this rocket model at all... OTOH there is a Nov 2021 Pravda video that says such "guided" 300mm rockets were planned for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nk1hSrExuE (The video shows completely irrelevant 122mm systems, only the audio is relevant.)